# preg_replace with lots of special characters

Tags: php, regex

I tend to lose track when I'm dealing with alot of special characters.

I have some urls (badly formatted, not consistent enough to use parse_url), and I want to replace all occurrences of the parameters ?dead and/or ?dead=some_text_here with nothing.

There might be other variables before and after.

Example urls:

```
http://www.url.com/?dead?dead=whatever_text&wow=test
http://www.url.com/?hello?dead=whatever_text
```

This is what I thought would work, but it doesnt.

```
$parsed_url = preg_replace("/(\?dead(?:=.*?)?)(?:\&|$|\?)/", "", $url);
```

What its supposed to do is check for "?dead", with an optional =value behind, then replace that with nothing. But this is also replacing the ? and &, if there is a parameter following the ?dead parameter. Also its only replacing 1 occurrence, not all.

It makes

```
http://www.url.com/?dead?dead=whatever_text&wow=test
```

Become

```
http://www.url.com/dead=whatever_text&wow=test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this pattern?

```
(\?dead(=[^&]*|))*
```

PHP Code:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\?dead(=[^&]*|))*/','',$sourcestring);
```

This will produce this output of your given urls:

```
http://www.url.com/&wow=test
http://www.url.com/&wow=test
http://www.url.com/?hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`\Q` and `\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) (as in QuotE) when dealing with lots of special characters.

The text between these delimiters will be treated literally.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$parsed_url = preg_replace("/\?dead(?:=[^&?]*)?/", "", $url);
```

`preg_replace` should match all occurances by default (the `$limit` parameter is `-1` by default).

This regex is very similar to yours but instead of `.*` it uses `[^&?]*` to match until the next `?` or `&`